# Can I debug this simple circuit without VNA and proper RF equipment?

Tags: pcb, rf, impedance-matching, debugging, demodulation

I am debugging a very simple circuit (existing PCB, not designed by me) that downconverts an AM modulated signal at 900 MHz:

[image]

The problem: What I measure at "Vo" does not match my LTspice simulations by quite a bit (I assume a constant unknown attenuation factor) and I do not have proper RF equipment (I have power supplies, multimeters, oscilloscope, an Ettus SDR and a very cheap and unreliable signal analyzer, but no VNA). I can basically only probe "Vo". For example, according to LTspice, the L-match is properly designed for 900 MHz but in measurements, the voltage would drop 10x for these values.

I tried to get creative and remove some unknowns by removing the L-match: I remove C1 and replace L2 with different resistors (0 Ohm... 1k). Here is what I get:

[image]

1. What could explain such profound differences? I tried adding various parasitics at various places but in the simulation, the voltage never decreases so rapidly as a function of resistance. As can be seen, for different input powers, the curves always fall off more gently.
2. Which kind of parasitics or effects could I have forgotten? What else could I try to model?
3. Is there any way to infer something about the RF nodes (bypassing the diodes)? I would really like to try something that does not need the diodes.
4. Could you think of any other clever way to simplify the setup further?

Comment: What are you using as the RF source? Your USRP? If so, how are you calibrating it?

Comment: Yes, USRP and as I said, I can’t (loopback config gives me expected results within 3dB, measurement with the cheap SA is off (by 1-3dB). However, as I said i assume an unknown, fixed attenuation (that I calibrate out in one measurement point). I’m confident it’s not the USRP but the circuit.

Comment: What did you do for parasitics? did you put all of them in?

Comment: @VoltageSpike All I could think of. I modeled package parasitics, transmission line, added series R+L, shunt Cs ... everything I try makes minor differences. In fact, to first order, all of these should result in attenuation. But from the figure above (comparing LTspice & measurements) you can see that it doesn't look like simple attenuation. If you have any ideas/suggestions what else I could try please let me know!